# ConcurrentModificationException, when changing adapter of ListView in it's onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, exception, android-arrayadapter

I want to replace clicked element from one ListView to another, but there is a problem: there is no methods to operate it from ListView, and when I change adapters - it gives me ConcurrentModificationException, because I change it in onItemClick. Here's problem part of code.

```
    datasource = new IngredientsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    final List<Ingredient> values_ing = datasource.getAllIngredients();
    final List<Ingredient> values_ch = values_ing.subList(0, 0);

    final ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> adapter_ing = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values_ing);
    list_ing.setAdapter(adapter_ing);

    final ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> adapter_ch = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values_ch);
    list_ch.setAdapter(adapter_ch);

    list_ing.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
            final Ingredient item = values_ing.get((int)id);
            list_ing.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                values_ing.remove(item);
                adapter_ing.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            });

            list_ch.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                values_ch.add(item);
                adapter_ch.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            });
```

And here's Logcat

```
 03-18 15:18:08.971 1027-1027/com.kochmarevsevolod.lazycook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                                                                             at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.size(AbstractList.java:360)
                                                                             at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
                                                                             at com.kochmarevsevolod.lazycook.Search_Page$1$2.run(Search_Page.java:73)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post proper logcat

Comment: move the add and remove statements inside a single thread(runnable) and check.

Comment: Nope, in previous version of code I did it in one thread, but still same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final Ingredient item = values_ing.get((int)id);
list_ing.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        values_ing.remove(item);
        adapter_ing.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
list_ch.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        values_ch.add(item);
        adapter_ch.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just tryed, but still same problem (

Comment: But your way still looks better, so I added your code (and also edited my question)

Comment: what's the code at: com.kochmarevsevolod.lazycook.Search_Page$1$2.run(Search_Page.java:73) ?

Comment: values_ch.add(item);

Comment: this means that while adding an item to values_ch you had an iterator or was messing with values_ch on another thread. check all accesses to this list and make sure they can't happen simultaneously